# Tomcat Database connection, am I doing this right?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jdbc

I'm just getting to grips with Tomcat and mySQL using the resource sharing method. Its all working fine, but I don't think I'm handling the connection right. I'm used to using JDBC direct to MySQL not on Tomcat.

My servlet calls intializeConnection() when it is first run, and never again. But I think that I should actually open and close the connection on each statement? Could someone adjust the code below to show the correct method of handling the connection, I'm a little confused.

```
public Connection con;

    public void intializeConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException{
        connect();
    }

    public void connect() throws SQLException, NamingException{

        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
        con = ds.getConnection();               

    } 

    public void excuteStatement(String query) throws SQLException{
        con.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
    }

    public ResultSet getResultSet(String query) throws SQLException{
        //not yet implemented

    }
```

My second question is, I don't know how to return a resultSet this way?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better design is to use a connection for each request and close it when you're done.  It'll scale better, in my opinion.

Have a look at the JDBC tutorial.  It'll show you how to get a ResultSet and much more:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Comment: Thanks Duffy, thats what I thought, open and close on each request.

Answer (score 3):

It is better if you use the connection pooling that is part of tomcat, All you have to do is define a connection pool in a file called context.xml and place that in your WebContent\META-INF folder if you are using eclipse (it has be in a folder called META-INF of the root of the war file) below is an example that I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/theDB" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/theDB"
        username="theusername" 
        password="thepassword" 
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
        maxWait="-1"
    />
</Context>
```

Then you can just open and close the connection in each request method. Also your code above for the lookup does not require two calls to jndi you can do a single call if you lookup the following string java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB

Also you don't want to be returning a ResultSet you should instead return the objects that represent the data in the result set, so if your query returns Customer objects your method for getResultSet should be called getCustomers and it should return a List<Customer>

JDBC is is tricky to work with correctly especially for exception handling and closing statements, connections, result sets ... etc I would highly recommend you use something like SpringJDBC template to make your code easier.